# Scheduled task output to html Coldfuson 2016

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

We ported to CF 2016 and now encounters error in scheduled task

This code used to work:

```
<cfschedule action="update" task="ia_scheduler" operation="HTTPRequest"
        url="#sURL#" startdate="#runDate#" starttime="#runTime#"
        path="#request.basepath#" file="ia_scheduler.html"
        resolveurl="yes" publish="yes" interval="3600" requesttimeout="900">
```

If I change the html to .txt it will work but I prefer it in html extension

```
file="ia_scheduler.html" to file="ia_scheduler.txt"
```

The error throws

```
Invalid extension of the file name.
Valid extensions are : log,txt.
```

How can I save to html file in cfschedule?

Comment: Sounds like a validation bug. Does it still generate HTML? [Report it](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/add_bug) and hope for a fix before CF2016 is EOL.

Comment: @Alex can I just report and give Stackoverflow question?

Comment: @alex it doesn't generate html it throws an error which I included in the question. invalid extension of the filename.

Comment: I was referring to changing it to one of the accepted file extensions: Does it stll generate HTML when you specify `ia_scheduler.txt`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've go through your issues. Here the name of the file in which to store the published output of the scheduled task. The file can only have a **.txt** or **.log** extension by default. You can add more extensions in
 `cfusion\lib\neo-cron xml.`

You can check that xml file have only **log,txt** in under string tag. So you have to add html also. Then check with html files too. Hopefully it will work. Thank you.

Comment: My vote put your reputation into the 4 digit category.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: Hi @DanBracuk Thank you for your vote. Sure I will send a beer :) . And I'm happy to reach 4 digit reputation. Thanks all for your voting.

Comment: @DanBracuk If we're talking about free beer here, it's almost worth risking a ban for creating a sock-puppet account to downvote his answer to bring it back to 3 digits, then vote with my regular account to get back to 4 and steal your beer. :-)

Comment: Amazing @Kannan.P works like a charm! Accepted and verified its working.